# How can I change Spiderman tag to 'spider-man'

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retagging

Spider-man should be tagged with [spider-man](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider-man) not [spiderman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spiderman). I can't make these changes, as they are too similar, what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Ask your friendly neighborhood moderator.

edit: Done.